# Cannot find module 'worker_threads' with node 16.14.2

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, next.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a monorepo project with multiple next.js apps inside thanks to [NX](https://nx.dev/). When running the command `sudo npx nx serve appname` on Ubuntu WSL I get the error `Cannot find module 'worker_threads'`.
I checked my node version with `node -v` and I'm running 16.14.2. I use nvm to manage nodejs versions.
The same command on Windows runs with no problems.
Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Comment: Are you on WSL 1 or 2? I just tried `nx serve` on my WSL 2 setup (Ubuntu 20.04.3; node v16.14.2 also managed by nvm) and it worked for me.

Comment: WSL version 2 @MarkG

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was running a node and npm version installed with apt and it was conflicting. I completely removed them and made sure I was using the latest LTS with NVM which fixed the issue.